# Invalid hook call with components from private repository

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have created a private repo of (soon to be) many components. Right now, there a button and a text field. These both work on there own (created using CRA).
This is the simple TextField:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classnames from "classnames";

import { Icon, IconType } from "../Icon";

interface Props {
    id?: string,
    name?: string,
    type?: "text" | "password" | "email" | "number",
    label?: string,
    error?: string,
    placeholder?: string,
    className?: string,
    iconType?: IconType,
    value?: string,
    onChange: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void,
    enabledShowHide?: boolean,
    autoComplete?: "email" | "current-password",
}

const TextField = ({ id, name, type = "text", label, error, placeholder, className, iconType, value, onChange, enabledShowHide, autoComplete }: Props) => {
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const toggleShowPassword = () => {
        setShowPassword(!showPassword);
    };

    const renderIcon = () => {
        if (enabledShowHide && type === "password") {
            return (
                <button type="button" onClick={toggleShowPassword} className="px-2 py-2 focus:outline-none transition text-primary-500 focus-within:text-primary-800">
                    {showPassword
                        ? <Icon className="h-5 w-5" type="eyeHide" />
                        : <Icon className="h-5 w-5" type="eyeShow" />}
                </button>
            );
        }
        if (error) {
            return <Icon className="text-red-500 pointer-events-none" type="error" aria-hidden="true" />;
        }
        return iconType
            ? <Icon className="h-5 w-5 text-primary-500 pointer-events-none" type={iconType} />
            : false;
    };

    const getPasswordDisplay = (): string => (showPassword ? "text" : "password");

    return (
        <div className="mb-4">
            <label htmlFor={id} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 pl-2">
                {label}
            </label>
            <div className="mt-1 relative shadow-sm">
                <input
                    type={type === "password" && enabledShowHide ? getPasswordDisplay() : type}
                    autoComplete={autoComplete}
                    name={name}
                    id={id}
                    className={classnames(
                        "block w-full pr-10 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm border-0 border-b placeholder-gray-400 transition",
                        "ring-0 focus:ring-0 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-offset-0 ring-opacity-50",
                        error
                            ? "border-red-500 text-red-900 placeholder-red-300 focus:ring-b-red-500 focus:border-red-500"
                            : "border-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 focus:ring-gray-300",
                        className,
                    )}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    aria-invalid={!!error}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={onChange}
                />
                <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-3">
                    {renderIcon()}
                </div>
            </div>

            {error && (
                <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600">
                    {error}
                </p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export { TextField };
```

When I try and use this private NPM package in a different project (again using CRA), I get the "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component" error from the useState.

Using the component like:

```
  <TextField onChange={() => {}} />
```

I'm using typescript in both projects.
The NPM repo has this in the `package.json`

```
      {
        "name": "react-package",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "private": true,
        "main": "./lib/cjs/index.js",
        "module": "./lib/esm/index.js",
        "types": "./lib/esm/index.d.ts",
        "peerDependencies": {
          "react": "^17.0.2",
          "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
        },
        "resolutions": {
          "@types/react": "^17.0.19",
          "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9"
        },
        "dependencies": {
          "@babel/core": "7.12.3",
          "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
          "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
          "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
          "@headlessui/react": "1.3.0",
          "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "0.4.3",
          "@svgr/webpack": "5.5.0",
          "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.2",
          "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
          "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
          "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
          "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
          "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
          "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.26.0",
          "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.5.0",
          "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
          "babel-jest": "^26.6.0",
          "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
          "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.7",
          "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.0",
          "bfj": "^7.0.2",
          "camelcase": "^6.1.0",
          "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
          "classnames": "^2.3.1",
          "css-loader": "4.3.0",
          "dotenv": "8.2.0",
          "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
          "eslint": "^7.11.0",
          "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
          "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.0",
          "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
          "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.3.1",
          "eslint-plugin-react": "7.20.3",
          "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.0.8",
          "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^3.9.2",
          "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.2",
          "file-loader": "6.1.1",
          "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
          "history": "4.10.1",
          "html-webpack-plugin": "4.5.0",
          "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
          "jest": "26.6.0",
          "jest-circus": "26.6.0",
          "jest-resolve": "26.6.0",
          "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.6.1",
          "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.11.3",
          "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.4",
          "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
          "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.2.1",
          "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
          "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
          "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
          "postcss-safe-parser": "5.0.2",
          "prompts": "2.4.0",
          "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
          "react-dev-utils": "^11.0.3",
          "react-refresh": "^0.8.3",
          "react-router": "^5.2.0",
          "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
          "resolve": "1.18.1",
          "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
          "sass-loader": "^10.0.5",
          "semver": "7.3.2",
          "store": "^2.0.12",
          "style-loader": "1.3.0",
          "terser-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
          "ts-pnp": "1.2.0",
          "typescript": "^4.1.2",
          "url-loader": "4.1.1",
          "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
          "webpack": "4.44.2",
          "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.1",
          "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
          "workbox-webpack-plugin": "5.1.4"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
          "@types/react": "^17.0.19",
          "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
          "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
          "autoprefixer": "9",
          "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
          "postcss": "7",
          "react": "^17.0.2",
          "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
          "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat"
        },
        "scripts": {
          "build": "yarn build:esm && yarn build:cjs",
          "build:esm": "tsc",
          "build:cjs": "tsc --module commonjs --outDir lib/cjs",
          "build:css": "tailwind build -i src/Styles/index.css -o src/build.css",
          "start": "node scripts/start.js",
          "test": "node scripts/test.js"
        },
        "eslintConfig": {
          "extends": [
            "airbnb"
          ]
        },
        "browserslist": {
          "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
          ],
          "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
          ]
        },
        "babel": {
          "presets": [
            "react-app"
          ]
        }
      }
```

I use this by having the example in the root of the package and reference it via
`"react-package": "link:..",`

Comment: Show the code of its usage, do this package has react and react-dom as peer dependency?

Comment: I have added this in an edit. But yes, peer dependency in the npm repo and react installed in the example repo. All ^17.0.2. Thanks

Comment: Does this module include React in its bundle? Show the build config and your package.json.

Comment: The error sounds like `TextField` is getting called as a function instead of being used as a component (via `<TextField...>`). Hope this helps you find the error.

Comment: I have added the package.json also. I'm referencing this via link because the example is in the root directory of the package. The build configuration for both is standard CRA and the only parts ive changed are in the package.json: `"build": "yarn build:esm && yarn build:cjs",`

Comment: I have just created a new project and linked to the package using `yarn link` and I still get the same error. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I figured this out.

My component library had `react` and `react-dom` installed. Event though these were in the peerDependencies section in the package.json.

Removing them (which removed them from peerDependencies also) and re-adding them to peerDependencies fixed the issue.

Also, one of my components uses `useLocation` so I also had to move that to the peerDependencies section to make this work.

Sorry if thats clear to some people but I hope this helps others :-)
Thanks